# Programming languages wrapper

Tags: c++, python, bash, swig

I have a python web application and I would like to run multiple scripts from it. Scripts are written in various languages, like bash, lua, perl, c++, ruby, etc. The thing is that I would like to first parse the script to replace the predefined building blocks with actual numbers. So for example, let's say I have the following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

ping -c 3 {{ip}}
```

Then I would like to pass that script into a wrapper with all the variables the script will need - in this case just the **ip** variable. The wrapper should replace all the variables with actual values, so if we inputed the ip variable as a value = 10.1.1.1, then the script should become:

```
#!/bin/bash

ping -c 3 10.1.1.1
```

And I want this functionality for all of the programming languages. So I'm using python, which should in turn use some kind of wrapper that accepts a script + arguments, and outputs corresponding output script.

I've found swig already, but don't know if it does what I want, so suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you want [m4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M4_%28computer_language%29), which would handle this easily for all scripting languages. C++, being a compiled language, would be a totally different undertaking, but I'll assume you didn't really mean that.

There are multiple free m4 implementations; it's already going to be on every Linux box.

You definitely don't want SWIG, it does something completely different.

Answer (score 5):

I would design the scripts to take **command line arguments**, read a common **configuration file**, or read **environment variables**, instead of trying to modify the internals of the scripts.

Are you really going to have your Python web application modify the C++ code, recompile it, and then run it?  Something about that seems wrong to me.  It would probably be slow.